# Website all blank after editing services.xml

Tags: xml, symfony

I'm currently doing an internship where I must use symfony2 (which I never used before and only discovered during the past week).

I needed to create a new page on the website (means new controller, new service, etc..).

But, came the time I had to modify services.xml by adding what I think is needed for my new page :

```
<parameter key="intranet.reunions_service.class">Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Service\ReunionsService</parameter>

<service id="intranet.reunions_service" class="%intranet.reunions_service.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <!-- <argument type="service" id="knp_paginator" /> -->
</service>
```

Also here is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Form\UsersType;
use Osaxis\IntranetBundle\Form\ReunionsType;

class ReunionsController extends Controller
{
    protected $reunionsService;

    /**
     * @Template("IntranetBundle:Reunions:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function reunionsAction()
    {
        $this->reunionsService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");
        $pagination = $this->reunionsService->getAllReunions($this->get('request')->get('page'));

        // parameters to template
        return array('pagination' => $pagination);
    }

}
```

And now all of my website is blank, no matter the page.

I repeat, I'm really new with symfony2. Could someone explain to me why it does that and what is horribly wrong with my code ? Thanks :)

Comment: In dev or in prod environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you clear the cache?

Locate the console binary, usually it is inside the app dir. Then do this:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Also make sure errors are visible. If you are developing, use the app_dev.php prefix in your url. It is possible that your service definition doesn't add up with the actual classes' constructor or you mistyped some of the argument parameters.

An error message would help, but clearing the cache and using the dev environment path should help you with debugging.